# Why initialize id when is inherited from super class in JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this super-class

```
open class Base(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) var id: Long = 0,
    @Column var userId: Long? = 0,
    @Column var created: Date = Date(),
    @Column var updated: Date = Date(),
    @Column var currency: String = ""
)
```

which I then inherit in the following class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
class Foo(
    @Column var name: String = "",
) : Base()
```

Now the compiler complains

> Persistent entity 'Foo' should have primary key

But the `id` is defined in `Base`. Why is it complaining?

Comment: Is it intentional that your `Foo` inherits from `BaseActivity` rather than from `Base`?

Comment: Do you have the Base marked as a MappedSuperclass or Entity so it knows to pick it up for annotation processing?

Comment: @JohnBollinger nope, that was a typo. I corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the `id` is defined in `Base`. Why is it complaining?

<s>Possibly because `Foo` does not appear to inherit from `Base`.  But even if it did inherit from `Base`,</s> annotations on the superclass and its members are of interest to JPA only if the superclass is a `@MappedSuperclass` or an `@Entity` itself.